# Simple algebra manipulation?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I am currently reading through this guide
http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ebender/CombText/ch-10.pdf
on generating functions and I can't figure out how on page three he went from this formula to the next 
$$\frac{1}{(1-y) - xy} = \frac{(\frac{1}{1-y})}{1 - \frac{xy}{1-y}}$$
It's got me stumped.

Comment: Divide both the numerator and denominator by $1 - y$.

Comment: No idea why that didn't just click.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> We can factor out  $1-y$ and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{(1-y)-xy}&=\frac{1}{(1-y)\left(1-\frac{xy}{1-y}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-y}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{xy}{1-y}}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying numerator and denominator by $$1-y\neq 0$$ we get
$$\frac{\frac{1-y}{1-y}}{(1-\frac{xy}{1-y})(1-y)}=\frac{1}{1-y-xy}$$